# CSS dynamic two column layout

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, multiple-columns

I need to create following layout using css

===== MOBILE ===== ===== ON DESKTOP ======

-----[1]-----                      -----[1]-----|-----[4]-----
-----[2]-----                      -----[2]-----|-----[5]-----
-----[3]-----                      -----[3]-----|-----[6]-----
-----[4]----- 
-----[5]----- 
-----[6]-----

===== MOBILE ==== ===== ON DESKTOP====

They above layout DOM structure will be as per the mobile layout order and also it is dynamic, if I removed [2] from the DOM [3] should take place of [2] not the [5]. How can I create a css layout with these condition is it possible to create with css?

Comment: put 1, 2, 3 in one div, 4, 5, 6 in a second. Then work with media queries to switch the containing divs from 50% to 100% width. If you want 4 to reflow on 3's spot when 2 is removed - that's another story...

Comment: Hi Swiss Mister, I tried this http://jsbin.com/paduqupipa/1/edit?html,css,output, its fails on that I want to reflow 4 to reflow on 3's spot, how can I make it possible can u guide me ? (also tried using bootstrap but seems not works for my issue. row>.col-sm-6+.col-xs-12*2).

Comment: @SwissMister, I'm interested that another story u mentioned :), can you just guide me some points.

Comment: "another story": Unless you are so lucky to be able to use @Terry's elegant solution with CSS columns, I believe you'd need to program the reflowing yourself with javascript. That's non-trivial and depends on more info than I see in the OP. Like the height of 1, 2, 3, etc. Good luck!

Comment: @Sudeep 's jsbin solution does not yet use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). But again: if you have that additional feature request of reflowing (4 -> 3), you'll have to go for something more complex anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [CSS columns](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/), which has been designed specifically for layout intentions like this.

**CSS columns**: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/6bz4a0ox/

Use the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <label for="">label</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="[1]">
    </div>
    <!-- more -->
</div>
```

And for the CSS, we make sure that we declare both the column count (which is 2, as you have wanted) with a minimum column width. I actually would recommend doing this instead of targetting mobile vs desktop, as fluid/responsive layouts should be catered to the content, not the device:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
     -webkit-columns: 2 200px;
        -moz-columns: 2 200px;
             columns: 2 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
     -moz-column-gap: 1em;
          column-gap: 1em;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: .5em;
}
.wrapper label {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
}
.wrapper label + input {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Hi @terry, I tested your code and found a issue in that, I removed [2] element from the markup and now the browser is rendering [4] input box bottom in next column, is there any way to fix that?http://jsfiddle.net/sharpshooter1990/27ygfwpr/1/ here is the tested version.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. The column flows the content from left to right, so it will fill up spaces on the left before moving to the right.

Comment: columns seems to have [very limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) at the moment. So it depends on your environment (intranet with controllable browser software versions vs. wide internet etc.).